# "QtQuick.Controls version 1.2 is not installed" when compiling the example for QMLRS

Tags: qml, qt5, rust

While trying to use [qmlrs](https://github.com/cyndis/qmlrs), I encountered this issue:

```
~/rustqml/qmlrs$ cargo run --example factorial
Compiling qmlrs v0.0.1 (file:///home/dally/rustqml/qmlrs)
Running target/debug/examples/factorial
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///home/dally/rustqml/qmlrs/examples/factorial_ui.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
file:///home/dally/rustqml/qmlrs/examples/factorial_ui.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
file:///home/dally/rustqml/qmlrs/examples/factorial_ui.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
file:///home/dally/rustqml/qmlrs/examples/factorial_ui.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
```

After searching, I installed `libqt5qml-quickcontrols`. I now get errors  about requiring version 1.2:

```
~/rustqml/qmlrs$ cargo run --example factorial
Running target/debug/examples/factorial
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///home/dally/rustqml/qmlrs/examples/factorial_ui.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" version 1.2 is not installed
```

Comment: Qml libs changes (usually) with Qt releases. `Controls`  reached version 1.3 currently. For each library you should install the one matching the required version or probably an higher version.

Comment: Have you installed version 1.2 of the package, as the error suggests?

Comment: I'm not sure how to install previous versions; do either of you know? Shepmater, BaCaRoZzo?

Comment: Use the `@` before the name to notify other users about the message, e.g. @Shepmater will be correctly  notified of this message. :) As for the library, controls were introduced in Qt 5.1 - version 1.0 - and thus you should download Qt 5.3 to obtain the correct 1.2 version.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo although you do have to spell it correctly... ^_^

Comment: Lol, Does it "mater" if I say that I've used the stackoverflow autocompletion @Shepmaster? No it doesn't...I was able to miss your name. A record! :D

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out in the qmlrs project find the file called `factorial_ui.qml` and change the line where it says:
change the version of QtQuick.Controls:
`import QtQuick.Controls 1.1` (in my case was 1.1 which solved my version)

Otherwise check out:
https://github.com/cyndis/qmlrs/blob/master/.travis.yml

```
language: rust
install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty main restricted universe multiverse" -y
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq libqt5core5a libqt5gui5 libqt5quick5 libqt5qml5 qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev cmake
```

to install the requirements they are located in the project;

I know my solution is quick hack to make it work; but hey I'm on the ground running with GUIs in Rust :)