# error with haskell & Qt5 quick on ubuntu

Tags: qt, haskell

I installed haskell on ubuntu (with sublime text 3) and I can get examples here working, using Qt (which I installed on ubuntu too) and the binding package hsqml.

but I tried to add a button to change a little the example and it does not work.

here is my qml file :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Item {
height: 266
Button {
    id: bouton
    x: 278
    y: 77
    text: qsTr("click me!")
    onClicked: texte.text="Hello!"
}

Text {
    id: texte
    x: 166
    y: 147
    width: 309
    height: 87
    text: qsTr("Text")
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    font.pixelSize: 76
}

}
```

---

and here is my haskell file:

---

```hs
import Graphics.QML
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = do
clazz <- newClass [
    defMethod' "factorial" (\_ txt ->
        let n = read $ T.unpack txt :: Integer
        in return . T.pack . show $ product [1..n] :: IO Text)]
ctx <- newObject clazz ()
runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
    initialDocument = fileDocument "exemple1.qml",
    contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

the error, when I launch the hs file from sublime text is:

```
 HsQML: file:///home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/exemple1.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" version 1.3 is not installed
```

I tried to find some clues on the net, but without success. 2 ways that did not succeeded were to search an ubuntu package containing the required libraries and to provide the good path to the good (ubuntu file?/sublime config file?)

can you help me?

EDIT : ANSWERS

```
lowley@lowley-GB-BXCE-3205:~$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3

lowley@lowley-GB-BXCE-3205:~$ ghc-pkg list
WARNING: there are broken packages.  Run 'ghc-pkg check' for more details.
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.16.0
   GLURaw-1.3.0.0
   GLUT-2.4.0.0
   HTTP-4000.2.8
   HUnit-1.2.5.2
   MonadCatchIO-mtl-0.3.0.5
   OpenGL-2.8.0.0
   OpenGLRaw-1.3.0.0
   QuickCheck-2.6
   array-0.4.0.1
   async-2.0.1.4
   attoparsec-0.10.4.0
   base-4.6.0.1
   bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
   binary-0.5.1.1
   bytestring-0.10.0.2
   case-insensitive-1.1.0.2
   cgi-3001.1.8.3
   containers-0.5.0.0
   deepseq-1.3.0.1
   directory-1.2.0.1
   extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4
   fgl-5.4.2.4
   filepath-1.3.0.1
   ghc-7.6.3
   ghc-prim-0.3.0.0
   hashable-1.2.1.0
   haskell-src-1.0.1.5
   haskell2010-1.1.1.0
   haskell98-2.0.0.2
   hoopl-3.9.0.0
   hpc-0.6.0.0
   html-1.0.1.2
   integer-gmp-0.5.0.0
   mtl-2.1.2
   network-2.4.1.2
   old-locale-1.0.0.5
   old-time-1.1.0.1
   parallel-3.2.0.3
   parsec-3.1.3
   pretty-1.1.1.0
   primitive-0.5.0.1
   process-1.1.0.2
   random-1.0.1.1
   regex-base-0.93.2
   regex-compat-0.95.1
   regex-posix-0.95.2
   rts-1.0
   split-0.2.2
   stm-2.4.2
   syb-0.4.0
   template-haskell-2.8.0.0
   text-0.11.3.1
   time-1.4.0.1
   transformers-0.3.0.0
   unix-2.6.0.1
   unordered-containers-0.2.3.0
   vector-0.10.0.1
   xhtml-3000.2.1
   zlib-0.5.4.1
/home/lowley/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.22.4.0
   Cabal-1.22.7.0
   GLURaw-1.4.0.2
   GLURaw-1.5.0.3
   HCodecs-0.5
   MonadRandom-0.4
   ObjectName-1.1.0.0
   OpenGL-2.9.2.0
   OpenGL-2.13.1.0
   OpenGLRaw-1.5.0.1
   OpenGLRaw-2.5.5.0
   StateVar-1.1.0.1
   aeson-0.7.0.6
   aeson-pretty-0.7.2
   ansi-terminal-0.6.2.3
   appar-0.1.4
   asn1-encoding-0.9.3
   asn1-parse-0.9.4
   asn1-types-0.3.1
   attoparsec-0.11.3.4
   auto-update-0.1.2.2
   base-orphans-0.4.4
   base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6
   base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1
   bifunctors-5
   binary-0.7.6.1
   blaze-builder-0.4.0.1
   blaze-html-0.8.1.1
   blaze-markup-0.7.0.3
   buildwrapper-0.9.1
   byteable-0.1.1
   byteorder-1.0.4
   bytestring-builder-0.10.6.0.0
   cabal-helper-0.6.1.0
   cabal-meta-0.4.1.3
   cairo-0.12.5.3
   cairo-0.13.1.0
   cereal-0.5.0.0
   cmdargs-0.10.13
   comonad-4.2.7.2
   conduit-1.2.5.1
   conduit-extra-1.1.9.1
   connection-0.2.5
   constraints-0.4.1.3
   contravariant-1.3.3
   control-monad-free-0.5.3
   convertible-1.1.0.0
   cookie-0.4.1.6
   cpphs-1.19.3
   cryptohash-0.11.6
   cryptonite-0.9
   data-default-0.5.3
   data-default-class-0.0.1
   data-default-instances-base-0.0.1
   data-default-instances-containers-0.0.1
   data-default-instances-dlist-0.0.1
   data-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1
   derive-2.5.22
   distributive-0.4.4
   djinn-ghc-0.0.2.3
   djinn-lib-0.0.1.2
   dlist-0.7.1.2
   dynamic-cabal-0.3.5
   either-4.4.1
   enclosed-exceptions-1.0.1.1
   exceptions-0.8.0.2
   extra-1.4.2
   fast-logger-2.4.1
   fclabels-2.0.2.3
   free-4.12.1
   ghc-mod-5.4.0.0
   ghc-paths-0.1.0.9
   ghc-pkg-lib-0.3.1
   ghc-syb-utils-0.2.3
   gio-0.12.5.3
   gio-0.13.1.0
   glade-0.12.5.0
   glib-0.12.5.4
   glib-0.13.2.1
   gtk-0.12.5.7
   haddock-2.13.2.1
   half-0.2.2.1
   haskell-docs-4.2.6
   haskell-generate-0.2.3
   haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1
   haskell-src-exts-1.17.0
   hasktags-0.69.1
   heap-0.6.0
   hex-0.1.2
   hlint-1.9.22
   hlint-1.9.23
   hlint-1.9.26
   honk-1.3.0.0
   hoogle-4.2.42
   hoogle-4.2.43
   hourglass-0.2.9
   hscolour-1.23
   hsqml-0.3.3.0
   hsqml-0.3.4.0
   http-api-data-0.2.1
   http-client-0.4.24
   http-client-tls-0.2.2
   http-conduit-2.1.8
   http-date-0.0.6.1
   http-types-0.9
   http2-1.2.0
   iproute-1.7.0
   js-flot-0.8.3
   js-jquery-1.11.3
   json-0.9.1
   lazysmallcheck-0.6
   lifted-async-0.7.0.1
   lifted-base-0.2.3.6
   markov-chain-0.0.3.3
   memory-0.10
   mime-types-0.1.0.6
   mmorph-1.0.4
   monad-control-1.0.0.4
   monad-journal-0.7.1
   monad-logger-0.3.15
   monad-loops-0.4.3
   mtl-2.2.1
   mwc-random-0.13.3.2
   nats-1.1
   newtype-0.2
   pango-0.12.5.3
   pango-0.13.1.0
   parallel-io-0.3.3
   path-pieces-0.2.1
   pem-0.2.2
   persistent-2.2.2.1
   persistent-sqlite-2.2
   persistent-template-2.1.3.6
   pipes-4.1.6
   polyparse-1.11
   portaudio-0.2.4
   prelude-extras-0.4.0.2
   profunctors-5.1.1
   psqueues-0.2.0.3
   pure-fft-0.2.0
   refact-0.3.0.1
   regex-tdfa-1.2.1
   resource-pool-0.2.3.2
   resourcet-1.1.6
   safe-0.3.9
   sarasvati-0.3.0.0
   scientific-0.3.4.2
   semigroupoids-5.0.0.4
   semigroups-0.18
   shake-0.15.5
   shelly-1.6.4
   silently-1.2.5
   simple-sendfile-0.2.21
   socks-0.5.4
   stm-chans-3.0.0.4
   streaming-commons-0.1.14.2
   strict-0.3.2
   stylish-haskell-0.5.14.3
   stylish-haskell-0.5.14.4
   system-fileio-0.3.16.3
   system-filepath-0.4.13.4
   tagged-0.7.3
   tagged-0.8.2
   tagsoup-0.13.5
   tar-0.4.2.2
   temporary-1.2.0.3
   text-1.2.1.3
   tls-1.3.3
   transformers-0.4.3.0
   transformers-base-0.4.4
   transformers-compat-0.4.0.4
   uniplate-1.6.12
   unix-compat-0.4.1.4
   utf8-string-0.3.8
   utf8-string-1.0.1.1
   vault-0.3.0.4
   vector-algorithms-0.7.0.1
   void-0.7.1
   wai-3.0.4.0
   warp-3.1.8
   word8-0.1.2
   x509-1.6.3
   x509-store-1.6.1
   x509-system-1.6.1
   x509-validation-1.6.3
   yaml-0.8.15.1
```

here are the other results:

```
lowley@lowley-GB-BXCE-3205:~$ sudo apt-get install qt*.dev
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Note : sélection de libnetworkmanagerqt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libdconf-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libmygpo-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libqt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libibus-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de licq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libprojectm-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libxs-compat-libzmq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libdbusmenu-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libmodemmanagerqt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libbpp-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libofono-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libindicate-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libcpufreq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libsoqt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libsignon-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libbpp-seq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libdaq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de liblightdm-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de sqldeveloper-package pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libpythonqt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libpq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libgsettings-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libsoqt-dev-common pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libzmq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libmumps-seq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libaccounts-qt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de librabbitmq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libghc-postgresql-libpq-dev-0.8.2.1-3c6b0 pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libpaq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libghc-deepseq-dev-1.3.0.1-5cc4c pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de golang-pq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libghc-deepseq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de perlqt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libghc-postgresql-libpq-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libsvnqt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de libzbarqt-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « qt*.dev »
Note : sélection de « ghc » au lieu de « libghc-deepseq-dev »
Note : sélection de « ghc » au lieu de « libghc-deepseq-dev-1.3.0.1-5cc4c »
Note : sélection de « libghc-postgresql-libpq-dev » au lieu de « libghc-postgresql-libpq-dev-0.8.2.1-3c6b0 »
Note : sélection de « libsoqt4-dev » au lieu de « libsoqt-dev »
ghc est déjà la plus récente version disponible.
ghc passé en « installé manuellement ».
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libxs-compat-libzmq-dev : Est en conflit avec: libzmq-dev
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

Comment: Could you show the output of `ghc --version` and `ghc-pkg list` do you use `stack`?

Comment: hello, thanks. I don't use stack and the answers are in an edit of my question.

Comment: sidenote: 7.6.3 is really old - shame on you ubuntu - thankfully you can get newer versions using [Herbert V. Riedels - ppa](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc) - also you should consider switching to [*stack*](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#ubuntu) so you never have to worry about those things again (well at least in almost all cases)

Comment: to the problem at hand: here I think you are missing some Qt dependencies unrelated to Haskell(bindings) - did you install all `qt*.dev` versions/packages? - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010184/qtquick-controls-version-1-2-is-not-installed-when-compiling-the-example-for-q) for a similar problem

Comment: [here are docs to the missing module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-controls-styles-qmlmodule.html) - see the [setup instructions here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html) - as far as I can thell there are [offline installers here](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) but you have to choose your licence carefully there (at least they ask for it)

Comment: @Carsten : I'd rather focus on making the Qt libs available, so I entered "sudo apt-get install qt*.dev" and I saw there are conflicts between libxs-compat-libzmq-dev and libzmq-dev. Do you know how I can fix this? The whole result is in an edit of my question. Anyway, is it really so important to download these libs? I mean, I downloaded Qt binaries from Qt site, but ran the setup and selected the destination path as a subfolder of my home directory. Maybe the problem comes from this.

Comment: I never tried building something with Qt so I sadly cannot tell you - but the missing module seems to be development related and usually you get rid of similar problems by looking at the right `...-dev` package - but you are right if you did grab the development binaries form the Qt side then those should be in there - I was not suggesting you install *all* of those for Qt though - the `*`in there was my ignorance of which is the right one showing :(

Comment: @Carsten : I have an other question : do you know if stack could autolmatically download the right Qt libraries?

Comment: I don't think so - seems like `hsqml` is not even on stackage so it will probably use the same setup vanilla cabal uses

Comment: well, it seems it is more or less resloved : I can compile my hs file with the statement "ghc mon-exemple.hs", but then it is a sublime text issue. Thanks !